# installed Google SDK but can't authenticate

Tags: bash, sdk

I am trying to install SDK using Cygwin as instructed here `https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/#Quick_Start`

after Cygwin is installed I follow the guide and then try to authenticate using the `gcloud auth login` command, but get the following returned and do not know how to remedy.

```
$ gcloud auth login
-bash: gcloud: command not found
```

sorry I am not that technical, so I am sorry this is fairly basic, but I have tried searching and can't find a solution, so thanks in anticipation for any help

Comment: First of all, Welcome to **SO**. Please move your question to super user.  [Please check how to ask question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks @jord (for reformatting the question too). Are saying I have to add su to the beginning of the command? If so I have tried and states the 'user root does not exist'

Comment: BTW I am running cygwin as administrator

Comment: No no what I was saying that stackoverflow community deals only with questions which are one or the other way related with programming problems. So you can move your question to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) That would I guess be the right place for your question

Comment: sorry... as you are featured in teh developers.google page it was the obviously location, but will try SU instead, thanks